# Connect to db server from an app server: (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have two servers: AppServer with IP 192.168.1.2 and DBServer with IP 192.168.1.3

On DBServer I have the database EMSMVC in the `DBSERVER\SQLEXPRESS` instance. The database is working.

On the AppServer in `web.config` I have:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=EMSMVC;Integrated Security=True;Server=192.168.1.3;user id=DBSERVER\admin;password=admin" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="EMSMVCEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EMSModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EMSModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EMSModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DBSERVER\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=EMSMVC;integrated security=True;Server=192.168.1.3;user id=admin;password=DBSERVER\admin;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I browse the app in the AppServer I get the following error:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.]

However, I'm not trying to connect using Anonymous logon.

Comment: Which connection string are you using?? The `DefaultConnection` is definitely missing a value for the `Data Source=` property  - it should be `Data Source=DBSERVER\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: @marc_s I'm using `DefaultConnection`. I have `connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=EMSMVC;Integrated Security=True;Server=192.168.1.3;user id=DBSERVER\admin;password=admin" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string is flawed with several problems:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=EMSMVC;Integrated Security=True;Server=192.168.1.3;user id=DBSERVER\admin;password=admin" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

1. You have **both** a `Data Source` (with no value) and a `Server` - you should use **one or the other** - but not both. Both basically mean the same thing - you neither of them is specifying the `\SQLEXPRESS` instance name ....
2. You're specifying an `User Id` (and password) in the connection string - but also `Integrated Security=True`, which means use the built-in Windows authorization - again: if you want to use `User Id`; then you **must NOT** also specify `Integrated Security` at the same time - this setting will take precedence over the specified `User Id`.

So your connection string should really be:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=DBSERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMSMVC;User id=DBSERVER\admin;password=admin" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

or using the IP address instead of the machine name:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMSMVC;User id=DBSERVER\admin;password=admin" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

or if you prefer the `Server=` instead of the `Data Source=` setting:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Server=192.168.1.3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMSMVC;User id=DBSERVER\admin;password=admin" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using now `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMSMVC;User id=DBSERVER\admin;password=admin" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` but I get  `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. `. Shall I try `User id=192.168.1.3\admin` instead?

Comment: It finally worked using a new user and enabling SQL Server and Windows Authentication.